# pry command not found after installing gem

Tags: ruby, pry

After installing the gem pry, and typing `pry` in terminal, i get an error saying that the command is not found:

```
Successfully installed pry-0.12.2
Parsing documentation for pry-0.12.2
Done installing documentation for pry after 1 seconds
1 gem installed
```

```
-bash: pry: command not found
```

Answer (score 1):

So much depends on the details of your ruby installation that its difficult to give you a recipe to follow that will work from this point, but the general answer to why you can't execute `pry` is that the `pry` binary is not in your PATH. If you find the place where your gem binaries live and add that to your PATH, then you will be able to execute `pry`. Exactly how to do that depends on how you've installed Ruby and how your environment is set up. For example, if you use rbenv, and want to use a binary immediately after installing it, then I know that you have to run `rbenv rehash`. But there may be other procedures to follow for other setups.

Maybe a simpler way for you to initiate a pry session is to execute `irb` instead, and from there you can `require 'pry'` and `Pry.start`

Comment: I installed an older version of ruby (2.5.1) and pry now seems to work perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you add `pry` to your Environment Variables (windows)

Write `env` in the start menu then pick `Edit the System Environment Variables` then go to tab `Advanced` then click on `Environment Variables`
In `User Variables` Select the `Path` then click `Edit` then `New` and past your ruby path for example `C:\Ruby26-x64\bin` (this directory if you go inside it you will see the pry there) 
And Click `ok` then `ok` then `ok`.

Now close your terminal and open it again (the problem should be solved after that) [try to restart your PC if it didn't solve, then open the terminal and try again]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue. It got resolved simply after I restarted my terminal (I use iTerm2 on Mac).